# ubuntu18.04 install problem

Tags: xubuntu

1. I install Ubuntu18.04 and win10 two system.
2. Ubuntu18.04 server USB startup can not format disk which likes Ubuntu16.04.
3. Xubuntu18.04 login desktop freeze, My PC use Nvidia display card.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify the second part of your question? I don't understand how it is worded. Also, are parts 2 and 3 actually separate questions?